# Extract data from Array of objects and Sort Alphabetically ( Simultaneously )

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array of objects:

```
var object = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Vehicles"
    },
    ...
```

I want to extract the "name" from each object and sort it in an array of "names" and then display each "name".

This is how I do it:

- I loop through each object and get "name" and push it in an array.
- Then, I loop through the array and display each "name" to the place I
  want.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/devphile/gtggpsov/)

Is there a way to do both actions at the same time ?

Comment: I guess it depends how you're wanting to display them. If you just want to log the console, you couuld just reference the name that you'd pushed. If you want to do it with an element, you could just append an element to a container in the loop. Thoughts?

Comment: I suspect that data comes from a SQL query and adding an `ORDER BY` clause right on the server would be trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're already sorting and appending the values, the question is how to get rid of one of the loops, and not iterate twice.

You can map and sort, and just join the array to get rid of the last loop and append everything in one go

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.lol').append(object.map(x => x.name).sort().join('<br />'));
});

var object = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Vehicles"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Mobiles & Tablets"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Electronics & Appliances"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Real Estate"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Home & Lifestyle"
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Jobs"
}, {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Services"
}, {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Education & Training"
}, {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Entertainment"
}, {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Pet & Pet Care"
}, {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Community"
}, {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Events"
}, {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "Matrimonial"
}];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="lol"></p>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I will try to update my question for a better understanding.

Answer (score 4):

A combination of `map` and `sort` will do the trick:

```js
var items = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Vehicles"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Lizards"
}];

var names = items.map(function(item) {
  return item.name;
}).sort();

console.log(names); // ["Lizards", "Vehicles"]
```

Also note that the data you are using is not JSON, it is simply an array of JavaScript objects.

Comment: Is there a way to append the names to his `<div>` element without having a second loop or function? Edit: adeneo just updated his answer with this

Comment: This is great and I will probably use this method. What I wanted though, was to for example `console.log()` each name individually without using 2 loops. Check [Answer HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510096/extract-json-data-and-sort-alphabetically-best-practice#answer-40510226) to see exactly what I wanted. Thanks anyway!